# How do I encode raw 48khz/32bits PCM to FLAC using Microsoft Media Foundation?

Tags: c++, audio, ms-media-foundation, flac

I created a SinkWriter that is able to encode video and audio using Microsoft's Media Foundation Platform.

Video is working fine so far but I have some troubles with audio only.

My PCM source has a sample rate of 48828hz, 32 bits per sample and is mono.

Everything is working well so far except for FLAC.

For instance the MP3 output is working more or less but has a wrong format. Regarding to [MSDN (MP3 Audio Encoder)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162907(v=vs.85).aspx) the MP3 encoder only supports 16 bits per sample as input. My PCM source as descriped above has 32 bits per sample.

However the export with MP3 is working cause the MF Platform seems like to have some kind of fallback and is using the MPEG Audio layer 1/2 (mpga) with 2 Channels, 32khz and a bitrate of 320kb/s.

Things start to get weird when I set the MF_MT_SUBTYPE to MFAudioFormat_FLAC. The export is working too but the quality of the audio is aweful. There's a lot of noise but I am able to recognize the audio. Regarding to VLC the FLAC file has a sample rate of 44,1khz, 8 bits per sample and is mono.

Does this mean the FLAC codec isn't able to work with the PCM I provide?

Has anyone had the same problem and was able to fix it?

**Update**

After doing some more research about this problem it seems like that my PCM Audio with a resolution of 32 Bit is too high. So currently I am trying to convert the 32 Bit PCM to 24 Bit for FLAC and 16 Bit for MP3 but with no luck so far. I keep you updated if I make some progress.

**--------**

**Update 2**

I've created a minimal example app that shows the problem I am facing.
It reads the 48khz32bit wave file and tries to encode it to flac.

When executing the `hr = pSinkWriter->BeginWriting();` command I get the error `0xc00d36b4` whice means `The data specified for the media type is invalid, inconsistent, or not supported by this object`.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

#include <comdef.h>

#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <Mferror.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ole32")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid")

using namespace System;


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

    IMFMediaType *pMediaType;
    IMFMediaType *pMediaTypeOut;
    IMFSourceReader *pSourceReader;
    IMFAttributes *pAttributes;
    IMFSinkWriter *pSinkWriter;

    hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(
        L"C:\\Temp\\48khz32bit.wav",
        NULL,
        &pSourceReader
    );

    hr = MFCreateAttributes(&pAttributes, 1);

    hr = pAttributes->SetGUID(
        MF_TRANSCODE_CONTAINERTYPE,
        MFTranscodeContainerType_WAVE
    );

    hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(
        L"C:\\Temp\\foo.flac",
        NULL,
        pAttributes,
        &pSinkWriter
    );

    hr = pSourceReader->GetCurrentMediaType(
        MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM,
        &pMediaType);

    hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeOut);

    hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(
        MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE,
        MFMediaType_Audio
    );

    hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(
        MF_MT_SUBTYPE,
        MFAudioFormat_FLAC
    );

    hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(
        MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND,
        48000
    );

    hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(
        MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS,
        1
    );

    hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(
        MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE,
        32
    );

    hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(
        MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND,
        (((32 + 7) / 8) * 1) * 48000
    );

    hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(
        MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT,
        ((32 + 7) / 8) * 1
    );

    DWORD nWriterStreamIndex = -1;

    hr = pSinkWriter->AddStream(pMediaTypeOut, &nWriterStreamIndex);

    hr = pSinkWriter->BeginWriting();

    _com_error err(hr);
    LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();

    for (;;)
    {
        DWORD nStreamIndex, nStreamFlags;
        LONGLONG nTime;
        IMFSample *pSample;

        hr = pSourceReader->ReadSample(
            MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM,
            0,
            &nStreamIndex,
            &nStreamFlags,
            &nTime,
            &pSample);

        if (pSample)
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"Write sample...\n");

            hr = pSinkWriter->WriteSample(
                nWriterStreamIndex,
                pSample
            );
        }

        if (nStreamFlags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_ENDOFSTREAM)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    hr = pSinkWriter->Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

**--------**

**Update 3**

I added the solution as answer.

**--------**

Initialize SinkWriter

```
HRESULT SinkWriter::InitializeSinkWriter(IMFSinkWriter **ppWriter, DWORD *pStreamIndex, DWORD *pAudioStreamIndex, LPCWSTR filename)
{
    *ppWriter = NULL;
    *pStreamIndex = NULL;
    *pAudioStreamIndex = NULL;

    IMFSinkWriter   *pSinkWriter = NULL;

    // Attributes
    IMFAttributes   *pAttributes;

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        MFCreateAttributes(
            &pAttributes,
            3
        )
    );

#if defined(ENABLE_HW_ACCELERATION)
    CComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL levels[] = { D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0 };

#if defined(ENABLE_HW_DRIVER)
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        D3D11CreateDevice(
            nullptr,
            D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
            nullptr,
            (0 * D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED) | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_VIDEO_SUPPORT,
            levels,
            ARRAYSIZE(levels),
            D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
            &device,
            nullptr,
            nullptr
        )
    );

    const CComQIPtr<ID3D10Multithread> pMultithread = device;
    pMultithread->SetMultithreadProtected(TRUE);
#else
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        D3D11CreateDevice(
            nullptr,
            D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_NULL,
            nullptr,
            D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED,
            levels,
            ARRAYSIZE(levels),
            D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
            &device,
            nullptr,
            nullptr)
    );
#endif

    UINT token;
    CComPtr<IMFDXGIDeviceManager> pManager;

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        MFCreateDXGIDeviceManager(
            &token,
            &pManager
        )
    );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pManager->ResetDevice(
            device,
            token
        )
    );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pAttributes->SetUnknown(
            MF_SOURCE_READER_D3D_MANAGER,
            pManager
        )
    );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pAttributes->SetUINT32(
            MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS,
            TRUE
        )
    );

#if (WINVER >= 0x0602)
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pAttributes->SetUINT32(
            MF_SOURCE_READER_ENABLE_ADVANCED_VIDEO_PROCESSING,
            TRUE
        )
    );
#endif
#else
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pAttributes->SetUINT32(
            MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS,
            TRUE
        )
    );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pAttributes->SetUINT32(
            MF_SOURCE_READER_ENABLE_VIDEO_PROCESSING,
            TRUE
        )
    );
#endif

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(
            filename,
            NULL,
            pAttributes,
            &pSinkWriter
        )
    );

    if (m_vFormat != VideoFormat::SWFV_NONE)
    {
        DX::ThrowIfFailed(
            InitializeVideoCodec(
                pSinkWriter,
                pStreamIndex
            )
        );
    }

    if (m_audFormat != AudioFormat::SWAF_NONE)
    {
        DX::ThrowIfFailed(
            InitializeAudioCodec(
                pSinkWriter,
                pAudioStreamIndex
            )
        );
    }

    // Tell the sink writer to start accepting data.
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pSinkWriter->BeginWriting()
    );

    // Return the pointer to the caller.
    *ppWriter = pSinkWriter;
    (*ppWriter)->AddRef();

    SAFE_RELEASE(pSinkWriter);
    return hr;
}
```

Initialize Audio Codec

```
HRESULT SinkWriter::InitializeAudioCodec(IMFSinkWriter *pSinkWriter, DWORD *pStreamIndex)
{
    // Audio media types
    IMFMediaType    *pAudioTypeOut = NULL;
    IMFMediaType    *pAudioTypeIn = NULL;

    DWORD           audioStreamIndex;

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // Set the output audio type.
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        MFCreateMediaType(
            &pAudioTypeOut
        )
    );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pAudioTypeOut->SetGUID(
            MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, 
            MFMediaType_Audio
        )
    );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pAudioTypeOut->SetGUID(
            MF_MT_SUBTYPE,
            AUDIO_SUBTYPE
        )
    );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pSinkWriter->AddStream(
            pAudioTypeOut,
            &audioStreamIndex
        )
    );

    // Set the input audio type
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        MFCreateMediaType(
            &pAudioTypeIn
        )
    );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pAudioTypeIn->SetGUID(
            MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE,
            AUDIO_MAJOR_TYPE
        )
    );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pAudioTypeIn->SetGUID(
            MF_MT_SUBTYPE,
            MFAudioFormat_PCM
        )
    );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pAudioTypeIn->SetUINT32(
            MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS,
            AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS
        )
    );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pAudioTypeIn->SetUINT32(
            MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE,
            AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE
        )
    );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pAudioTypeIn->SetUINT32(
            MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT,
            AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT
        )
    );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pAudioTypeIn->SetUINT32(
            MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND,
            AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND
        )
    );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pAudioTypeIn->SetUINT32(
            MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND,
            AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND
        )
    );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        pSinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(
            audioStreamIndex,
            pAudioTypeIn,
            NULL
        )
    );

    *pStreamIndex = audioStreamIndex;

    SAFE_RELEASE(pAudioTypeOut);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pAudioTypeIn);

    return hr;
}
```

Push audio data

```
HRESULT SinkWriter::PushAudio(UINT32* data)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_FALSE;

    if (m_isInitializing)
    {
        return hr;
    }

    IMFSample *pSample = NULL;
    IMFMediaBuffer *pBuffer = NULL;
    BYTE *pMem = NULL;

    size_t cbBuffer = m_bufferLength * sizeof(short);   

    // Create a new memory buffer.
    hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(cbBuffer, &pBuffer);

    // Lock the buffer and copy the audio frame to the buffer.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pBuffer->Lock(&pMem, NULL, NULL);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        CopyMemory(pMem, data, cbBuffer);
    }

    if (pBuffer)
    {
        pBuffer->Unlock();
    }

    if (m_vFormat == VideoFormat::SWFV_NONE && m_audFormat == AudioFormat::SWAF_WAV)
    {
        DWORD cbWritten = 0;

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = m_pByteStream->Write(pMem, cbBuffer, &cbWritten);
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            m_cbWrittenByteStream += cbWritten;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Set the data length of the buffer.
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pBuffer->SetCurrentLength(cbBuffer);
        }

        // Create media sample and add the buffer to the sample.
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = MFCreateSample(&pSample);
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pSample->AddBuffer(pBuffer);
        }

        // Set the timestamp and the duration.
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pSample->SetSampleTime(m_cbRtStartVideo);
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pSample->SetSampleDuration(m_cbRtDurationVideo);
        }

        // Send the sample to the Sink Writer
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = m_pSinkWriter->WriteSample(m_audioStreamIndex, pSample);
        }

        /*if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            m_cbRtStartAudio += m_cbRtDurationAudio;
        }*/

        SAFE_RELEASE(pSample);
        SAFE_RELEASE(pBuffer);
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Comment: It is a good question itself but lacks detail. Are you creating MP4? You don't show Sink Writer setup, neither you show relevant code. FLAC support for sure lacks MSDN documentation and hence the confuse.

Comment: In this example I am creating only audio files. So I thought that the configuration of the audio part should be enought. If you need more infos I could update my question. After some research it seems like I have to convert my 32 Bit PCM to 24 or 16 Bit PCM to make it work.

Comment: 32-bit is odd, make sure it isn't encoded in floating point.  FLAC maxes out at 24-bits.

Comment: I know its odd. The device unfortunalety sends this king-size PCM data in INT32 and not in floating points.

Comment: Would you be so kind to show me your implementation?

Comment: Thank you for this. I see you are using the Source Reader. The problem I have is that my Input Stream is 32 Bit PCM. What is yours in that example?

Comment: Hmmm... Then I don't get it why my implementation isnt working. I looks the same as yours except the initalization of the sinkwriter.

Comment: Maybe the difference is that you get the pMediaType from the source reader while I create it from scratch.

Comment: Would it help to provide the critical parts of my implementation? The initialization of the sinkwriter and the part where I write the samples to to it?

Comment: It is your question and you decide what should be a part of it. Perhaps you would even find the problem while updating this question and reviewing your code.

Comment: I added the code that initialize the sinkwriter and how's the audio data gets pushed to it.

Comment: I added a minimal example in update 2 that should be possible to compile after copy and paste. That minimal app shows the problem that I am facing.

Comment: I realized that the file I got in my app is not actually FLAC. It's a PCM WAV file due to a small mistake in my code, and API ignoring the rest of the mismatch. MF WAV sink is incompatible with FLAC as it seems, I will look later into the details.

Comment: That would be great! Thanks!

Comment: (I cleant up obsoelete comments above and added an answer explaining the details of the problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve the problem. It wasn't that hard to be honest. But that is always the case if you know how to achieve something ;).

I created a copy and paste example below to give an idea how to implement FLAC encoding with Microsoft Media Foundation.

The missing piece of the puzzle was the [MFTranscodeGetAudioOutputAvailableTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388655(v=vs.85).aspx). This function lists all the available output formats from an audio encoder.

If you are not sure what MFTs are supported by the operation system you can call [MFTEnumEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388652(v=vs.85).aspx) first. This gives you a list of all the available MFTs. In my case with windows 10 there's the FLAC MFT that is defined like this.

```
Name: Microsoft FLAC Audio Encoder MFT
Input Types: 1 items:
    Audio-PCM
Class identifier: 128509e9-c44e-45dc-95e9-c255b8f466a6
Output Types: 1 items:
    Audio-0000f1ac-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71
Transform Flags: 1
Transform Category: Audio Encoder
```

So the next thing I did was to create the source reader and get the current media type. The important values for me are sample rate, bit rate and channels.

Then I created a `GetOutputMediaTypes` function that needs the requested audio format, sample rate, bit rate, channels and a reference to the IMFMediaType.

The `MFTranscodeGetAudioOutputAvailableTypes` function returns all available types for the MFAudioFormat_flac GUID.

After getting the count of the available media types with `hr = pAvailableTypes->GetElementCount(&dwMTCount);` I am able to iterate through them and check if a type is supporting my request. If that's the case I return the media type.

The last part is the easiest one.

First add the output media type to the sinkwriter to get the stream index.

```
DWORD dwWriterStreamIndex = -1;

// Add the stream
hr = pSinkWriter->AddStream(
    pOuputMediaType,
    &dwWriterStreamIndex
);
```

Then set the input type and call `pSinkWriter->BeginWriting();` so the sinkwriter starts to accepting data.

```
// Set input media type
hr = pSinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(
    dwWriterStreamIndex,
    pInputType,
    NULL
);

// Tell the sink writer to accept data
hr = pSinkWriter->BeginWriting();
```

If the output and input media type is correctly set, BeginWriting should return 0 as HRESULT.

We should get no error because we are using the media type the function `MFTranscodeGetAudioOutputAvailableTypes` is providing.

The last step is to read all samples from the source reader and write it through the sinkwriter into the flac container.

**Done :)**

I hope I could help with this answer.

**Also thanks to Roman R.**

**Update**

This sample is only working with Audio-PCM formats from 4 bits to 24 bits. If you want to encode an 32 Bit Audio-PCM you have to resample it first and then encode it.

**--------**

Here's the minimal example app.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

#include <atlstr.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <exception>

#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfplay.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <Audioclient.h>
#include <mferror.h>
#include <Wmcodecdsp.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "mf.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplay.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "wmcodecdspuuid")


inline void ThrowIfFailed(HRESULT hr)
{
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // Get the error message
        _com_error err(hr);
        LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();

        OutputDebugString(L"################################## ERROR ##################################\n");
        OutputDebugString(errMsg);
        OutputDebugString(L"\n################################## ----- ##################################\n");

        CStringA sb(errMsg);
        // Set a breakpoint on this line to catch DirectX API errors
        throw std::exception(sb);
    }
}

template <class T> void SafeRelease(T **ppT)
{
    if (*ppT)
    {
        (*ppT)->Release();
        *ppT = nullptr;
    }
}

using namespace System;

HRESULT GetOutputMediaTypes(
    GUID cAudioFormat,
    UINT32 cSampleRate,
    UINT32 cBitPerSample,
    UINT32 cChannels,
    IMFMediaType **ppType
)
{
    // Enumerate all codecs except for codecs with field-of-use restrictions.
    // Sort the results.
    DWORD dwFlags =
        (MFT_ENUM_FLAG_ALL & (~MFT_ENUM_FLAG_FIELDOFUSE)) |
        MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SORTANDFILTER;

    IMFCollection   *pAvailableTypes = NULL;    // List of audio media types.
    IMFMediaType    *pAudioType = NULL;         // Corresponding codec.

    HRESULT hr = MFTranscodeGetAudioOutputAvailableTypes(
        cAudioFormat,
        dwFlags,
        NULL,
        &pAvailableTypes
    );

    // Get the element count.
    DWORD dwMTCount;
    hr = pAvailableTypes->GetElementCount(&dwMTCount);

    // Iterate through the results and check for the corresponding codec.
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwMTCount; i++)
    {
        hr = pAvailableTypes->GetElement(i, (IUnknown**)&pAudioType);

        GUID majorType;
        hr = pAudioType->GetMajorType(&majorType);

        GUID subType;
        hr = pAudioType->GetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, &subType);

        if (majorType != MFMediaType_Audio || subType != MFAudioFormat_FLAC)
        {
            continue;
        }

        UINT32 sampleRate = NULL;
        hr = pAudioType->GetUINT32(
            MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND,
            &sampleRate
        );

        UINT32 bitRate = NULL;
        hr = pAudioType->GetUINT32(
            MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE,
            &bitRate
        );

        UINT32 channels = NULL;
        hr = pAudioType->GetUINT32(
            MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS,
            &channels
        );

        if (sampleRate == cSampleRate
            && bitRate == cBitPerSample
            && channels == cChannels)
        {
            // Found the codec.
            // Jump out!
            break;
        }       
    }

    // Add the media type to the caller
    *ppType = pAudioType;
    (*ppType)->AddRef();
    SafeRelease(&pAudioType);

    return hr;
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // Initialize com interface
    ThrowIfFailed(
        CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)
    );

    // Start media foundation
    ThrowIfFailed(
        MFStartup(MF_VERSION)
    );

    IMFMediaType        *pInputType = NULL;
    IMFSourceReader     *pSourceReader = NULL;
    IMFMediaType        *pOuputMediaType = NULL;
    IMFSinkWriter       *pSinkWriter = NULL;

    // Create source reader
    hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(
        L"C:\\Temp\\48khz24bit.wav",
        NULL,
        &pSourceReader
    );

    // Create sink writer
    hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(
        L"C:\\Temp\\foo.flac",
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &pSinkWriter
    );

    // Get media type from source reader
    hr = pSourceReader->GetCurrentMediaType(
        MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM,
        &pInputType
    );

    // Get sample rate, bit rate and channels
    UINT32 sampleRate = NULL;
    hr = pInputType->GetUINT32(
        MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND,
        &sampleRate
    );

    UINT32 bitRate = NULL;
    hr = pInputType->GetUINT32(
        MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE,
        &bitRate
    );

    UINT32 channels = NULL;
    hr = pInputType->GetUINT32(
        MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS,
        &channels
    );

    // Try to find a media type that is fitting.
    hr = GetOutputMediaTypes(
        MFAudioFormat_FLAC,
        sampleRate,
        bitRate,
        channels,
        &pOuputMediaType);

    DWORD dwWriterStreamIndex = -1;

    // Add the stream
    hr = pSinkWriter->AddStream(
        pOuputMediaType,
        &dwWriterStreamIndex
    );

    // Set input media type
    hr = pSinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(
        dwWriterStreamIndex,
        pInputType,
        NULL
    );

    // Tell the sink writer to accept data
    hr = pSinkWriter->BeginWriting();

    // Forever alone loop
    for (;;)
    {
        DWORD nStreamIndex, nStreamFlags;
        LONGLONG nTime;
        IMFSample *pSample;

        // Read through the samples until...
        hr = pSourceReader->ReadSample(
            MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM,
            0,
            &nStreamIndex,
            &nStreamFlags,
            &nTime,
            &pSample);

        if (pSample)
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"Write sample...\n");

            hr = pSinkWriter->WriteSample(
                dwWriterStreamIndex,
                pSample
            );
        }

        // ... we are at the end of the stream...
        if (nStreamFlags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_ENDOFSTREAM)
        {
            // ... and jump out.
            break;
        }
    }

    // Call finalize to finish writing.
    hr = pSinkWriter->Finalize();

    // Done :D
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So, Microsoft introduced a FLAC Media Foundation Transform (MFT) Encoder `CLSID_CMSFLACEncMFT` in Windows 10, but the codec remains undocumented at the moment.

[Supported Media Formats in Media Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757927) is similarly out of date and does not reflect presence of recent additions.

I am not aware of any comment on this, and my opinion is that the codec is added for internal use but the implementation is merely a standard Media Foundation components without licensing restrictions, so the codecs are unrestricted too by, for example, [field of use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940327) limitations.

This stock codec seems to be limited to 8, 16 and 24 bit PCM input options (that is, not 32 bits/sample - you need to [resample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819070) respectively). The codec is capable to accept up to 8 channels and flexible samples per second rate (48828 Hz is okay).

Even though the codec (transform) seems to be working, if you want to produce a file, you also need a suitable container format (multiplexer) which is compatible with `MFAudioFormat_FLAC` (the identifier has 7 results on Google Search at the moment of the post, which basically means noone is even aware of the codec). Outdated documentation does not reflect actual support for FLAC in stock media sinks.

I borrowed a custom media sink that writes a raw MFT output payload into a file, and such FLAC output is playable as the FLAC frames contain necessary information to parse the bitstream for playback.

[image]

For the reference, the file itself is: [20180224-175524.flac](http://alax.info/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/20180224-175524.flac).

An obvious candidate among stock media sinks [WAVE Media Sink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302112) is unable to accept FLAC input. Nevertheless it potentially could, the implementation is presumably limited to simpler audio formats.

AVI media sink might possibly take FLAC audio, but it seems to be impossible to create an audio only AVI.

Among other media sink there is however a media sink which can process FLAC: [MPEG-4 File Sink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757763). Again, despite the outdated documentation, the media sink takes FLAC input, so you should be able to create .MP4 files with FLAC audio track.

Sample file: [20180224-184012.mp4](http://alax.info/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/20180224-184012.mp4). "FLAC (framed)"

[image]

To sum it up:

- FLAC encoder MFT is present in Windows 10 and is available for use; lacks proper documentation though
- One needs to take care of conversion of input to compatible format (no direct support for 32-bit PCM)
- It is possible to manage MFT directly and consume MFT output, then obtain FLAC bitstream
- Alternatively, it is possible to use stock MP4 media sink to produce output with FLAC audio track
- Alternatively, it is possible to develop a custom media sink and consume FLAC bitstream from upstream encoder connection

Potentially, the codec is compatible with [Transcode API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485863), however the restrictions above apply. The container type needs to be `MFTranscodeContainerType_MPEG4` in particular.

The codec is apparently compatible with [Media Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703988) API, presumably it is good for use with [Sink Writer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819461) API either.

In your code as you attempt to use Sink Writer API you should similarly either have MP4 output with input possibly converted to compatible format in your code (compatible PCM or compatible FLAC with encoder MFT managed on your side). Knowing that MP4 media sink overall is capable to create FLAC audio track you should be able to debug fine details in your code and fit the components to work  together.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this explanation! First I'll try to read a 48kHz/24Bit wave and try to convert it to flac. When this is working I hope I am able to create the flac file from my PCM stream aswell. As you said first I have to resample it from 32bit to 24bit.

Comment: To keep you up to date. I tried to achieve the same with NAudio for c# because it uses Media Foundation aswell. I was able to make it work after looking through the code and with the tips you gave me. Now I try to implement the same into my c++ application. When I am done I will update my post with the final solution to this problem.

Comment: I added my final solution as answer. Thank you for your help @Roman R.